# How to change the directory of file_create_url to default for a custom domain

Tags: 7, files, uri

Suppose, we have a file: /sites/default/files/picture.jpg

Drupal is installed into a subdirectory: /drupal. There are 2 domains, attached to the site:

1. exchange
2. exchange-test (uses different DB)

---

```
 | domain        | settings.php path     |
 |---------------+-----------------------+
 | exchange      | /sites/default/       |
 | exchange-test | /sites/exchange-test/ |
```

When we call

```
print file_create_url('public://picture.jpg');
```

we get:

```
| site          | result                                        |
|---------------+-----------------------------------------------|
| exchange      | /drupal/sites/default/files/picture.jpg       |
| exchange-test | /drupal/sites/exchange-test/files/picture.jpg |
```

But the file is stored in default directory even for `exchange-test` domain.

As far as I could find, the path is being generated, using [function conf_path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/conf_path/7). It scans the config directory to find a subdir with current domain name:

```
 $server = explode('.', implode('.', array_reverse(explode(':', rtrim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.')))));
  for ($i = count($uri) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    for ($j = count($server); $j > 0; $j--) {
      $dir = implode('.', array_slice($server, -$j)) . 
             implode('.', array_slice($uri, 0, $i));
      if (isset($sites[$dir]) && 
          file_exists(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $confdir . '/' . $sites[$dir])) {
            $dir = $sites[$dir];
      }
      if (file_exists(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $confdir . '/' . $dir . '/settings.php') || 
         (!$require_settings && file_exists(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $confdir . '/' . $dir))) {
            $conf = "$confdir/$dir";
            return $conf;
      }
    }
  }
```

If found, it uses this directory as files path.

So, one way is to temporarily change `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'exchange';
print file_create_url('public://picture.jpg');
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'exchange-test';
```

Will give the correct result. But this trick seems clumsy to me. Is there any way to get the default directory without such hacks?

Comment: try setting the public file system path in your -test site to match that of the other in /admin/config/media/file-system

Comment: @Geoff Can you put your comment as an answer, so I could close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the public file system path in your -test site to match that of the other in /admin/config/media/file-system